# Grails excel-import plugin Numbers populated as real with exponent

Tags: grails, import-from-excel

I am trying to import a ms-excel 2007 sheet using excel-import plugin. It was simple to integrate with my project and I found it working as expected until I noticed that the number values in the cells are populated as real numbers with exponent. 
For example if the cell contains value 9062831150099 -(populated as)->9.062831150099E12 i.e.

```
         A              |
    _____________________
    Registration Number |
    ____________________
    9062831150099
```

Is populated as: `[RegNum:9.062831150099E12]`

Anyone could suggest me how I can change this representation back to its original format keeping its type as number?

Answer (score 0):

Missed it at the first attempt but I figured out how to to achieve it:

When invoking the key methods (the ones that process cellMap and columnMaps) for example `List bookParamsList = excelImportService.columns(workbook, CONFIG_BOOK_COLUMN_MAP)` or `Map bookParams = excelImportService.cells(workbook, CONFIG_BOOK_CELL_MAP )` 
There is also ability to pass in configuration information, i.e. to specify what to do if a cell is empty (i.e. to provide a default value), to make sure a cell is of expected type, etc.

So in my case I created a configuration parameter Map of properties of the object and passed it to the above methods. i.e.

```
Class UploadExcelDataController {
    def excelImportService

    static Map CONFIG_BOOK_COLUMN_MAP = [
              sheet:'Sheet1', 
              startRow: 2,
              columnMap:  [
                      'A':'registrationNumber',
                      'B':'title',
                      'C':'author',
                      'D':'numSold',
              ]
      ]

    static Map configBookPropertyMap = [
        registrationNumber: ([expectedType: ExpectedPropertyType.IntType, defaultValue:0])
        ]

    def uploadFile(){
    ...
    List bookParamsList = excelImportService.columns(workbook, CONFIG_BOOK_COLUMN_MAP,configBookPropertyMap )
    ...
    }
}
```